# AngularJS - Modal view not showing

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Trying to get my modal view appear but it's not currently showing:

AngularJS:

```
$scope.openModal = function (row) {
    var uibModalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: "views/modals/view.html",
        controller: 'ModalCtrl',
        backdrop  : 'static',
        resolve: {
            row: function () {
                return row;
            },
            SpringDataRestService: function () {
                return SpringDataRestService;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 no-padding-right pull-right">
    <span class="pull-right padding-5 padding-right-10">
        <a href type="button" class="btn btn-sm shiny"
           ng-click="openModal()">Create New User</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: version of ui-bootstraptpls and the order of scripts in which you are adding in index.html? and any error if you are getting it in console?

Comment: Those `resolve` functions look sketchy. What are you trying to accomplish with them?

Comment: Do you try this commenting,
                SpringDataRestService: function () {
                    return SpringDataRestService;
                } this line of code?